# Weighted Vertex Cover and Linear Programming

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

I want to prove the statement described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235224/vertex-cover-linear-program-extreme-point).
The answer given is great, though the way I understand it, it only proves $x_i \in \{0, \frac12, 1\}$ or $x_i>1$.

I would like to show that $x_i\not>1$, but don't know how to go about it, and would appreciate help.

Thanks!

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that all your weights $w_i$ are nonnegative?

Comment: Indeed you are.

Comment: In that case, whenever $x_i > 1$, reducing $x_i$ to some smaller amount would give you a cheaper solution. The only problem would be if you made the solution infeasible, by violating one of the constraints. Try convincing yourself that you'd be able to reduce any variable exceeding $1$ without accidentally violating some constraint.

Comment: I understand that. But if I understand what you're saying, you're talking about optimal BFS, and the question is about any BFS (even non optimal).

Comment: Oops, sorry about that -- I read the question too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further thought, you can probably use a variant of the idea we discussed in the comments. The key is that the polytope you care about doesn't actually depend on the weight vector *at all*, only on the constraints. You may have seen the argument that, given a set of constraints, every BFS $x$ has a cost vector $w$ such that $x$ is the unique solution that minimizes $w\cdot x$ subject to your constraints. (This is Lemma 2.2 in my copy of Papadimitriou--Steiglitz.)

In particular, if we renumber variables so that $x_1, \ldots, x_t$ are the variables used in the basis, then putting $w_i = 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, t$ and $w_i = 1$ otherwise forces every optimal solution to have $x_j = 0$ for $j \notin 1, \ldots, t$, and therefore forces every optimal solution to be the BFS corresponding to $1, \ldots, t$.

Now if some $x_i > 1$ in our BFS, then reducing $x_i$ to $1$ would give another feasible solution with cost $0$ for the weight vector we constructed, contradicting the uniqueness of the solution.